# correct way to view file from ftp server laravel NAS Synology

Tags: laravel, ftp, synology, nas

```
    public function gambarObjective(Request $request)
    {
        $exist = Storage::disk('emr_nas')->exists('3mcTLZuI0O.jpeg');
        if ($exist) {
            $mime = Storage::disk('emr_nas')->mimeType('3mcTLZuI0O.jpeg');
            $get = Storage::disk('emr_nas')->get('3mcTLZuI0O.jpeg');
            header("Content-type: $mime");
            echo $get;
        } else {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

I have a controller that return a file like image or anything (not auto download but previewing it). It is work but i don't know am i doing it right? *please note it's not for upload, but previewing it only